# AngularJS get DOM element after push

Tags: angularjs

i'm using ng-repeat to display some array values (messages). How do i get the corresponding DOM element after pushing it to the messages array?

I want to add and remove a class(es) from the added dom element.

Thank you,
Bernhard

Comment: Can you elaborate a little, why do you want to get the DOM element that was created by ngRepeat? What do you plan on doing with it?

Comment: please provide a plunkr or jsfiddle

Comment: I want to add and remove a class(es) from the added dom element

Comment: Can you elaborate on the purpose of adding and removing CSS classes? Is this to highlight the latest, or provide an animation affect? The reason I ask, Hugo mentions this as well, this is not the correct way of using AngularJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular way is not to directly manipulate the DOM but to use the directives provided to you by the framework. To change the CSS classes applied to an element, use [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass), [ngClassEven](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassEven), and [ngClassOdd](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassOdd).

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in items">
     <span ng-class="{active: isActive(item)}">{{item}}</span>
 </div>
```

The parameter to ngClass is a JavaScript object which keys are the names of the CSS classes, and values are expressions. For each key-value pair, if the expression results in true, the class is added, otherwise it is removed.

ngClassEven and ngClassOdd can be used to apply classes only to even or odd elements of the repetition.

Comment: Thank you! If i want to change any other attribute, e.g. palceholder, i would use placeholder="{{ item.placeholder }}" - for example?